# Непонятен код в Pipelines.RIO

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

Ковыряю исходники [`System.IO.Pipelines.Networking.Windows.RIO`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/System.IO.Pipelines.Networking.Windows.RIO/Internal/Winsock/RIOImports.cs), непонятен следующий момент:

```
public unsafe static RegisteredIO Initalize(IntPtr socket)
{
    UInt32 dwBytes = 0;
    RioExtensionFunctionTable rio = new RioExtensionFunctionTable();
    Guid rioFunctionsTableId = new Guid("8509e081-96dd-4005-b165-9e2ee8c79e3f");

    int True = -1;
    int result = setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TcpNodelay, (char*)&True, 4);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        var error = WSAGetLastError();
        throw new Exception($"ERROR: setsockopt TCP_NODELAY returned {error}");
    }
}
```

Как `int True` может быть равно `-1`? Это какая то магия между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом или банально ошибка?

Comment: Объявляется переменная с именем `True`, которая затем передаётся в качестве параметра `optval` функции `optname()`. Согласен, странно, что компилятор позволяет перекрывать объявлениями ключевые слова языка. Но по смыслу строка `int result = ...` проста: *установить для `socket` параметр `TcpNodelay` в `-1`, имеющий смысл истины*.

Comment: @Arhad а где здесь ключевое слово языка?

Comment: О чем вопрос вообще??? С чего бы это вдруг значение `-1` у переменной типа `int` вызывает удивление или вопросы?

Comment: @alexolut, если `True` — это *не* ключевое слово, то где объявлена константа с этим именем и каково её значение?

Comment: @Arhad нет тут никакой константы, `True` это имя **переменной**, такое же имя как и `result` строкой ниже.

Comment: @alexolut, после объявления — да. Но до него это было ключевое слово языка (которые как бы являются зарезервированными). Получается, с таким же успехом можно объявить переменные с именами, допустим, `const` и `if`.

Comment: @Arhad Вы, кажется, забыли, что регистр важен в языках типа C#. И `true` отличается от `True`.

Answer (score 2):

По идее должно было хватить и единицы, но `-1` в битовом представлении будет давать все единицы, что как бы дает максимально отличный от нуля вариант. А так как всё, не являющееся нулем есть *истина*, то и минус единица вполне подходит.

Явной булевой переменной тут вообще не используется при передаче между управляемым и неуправляемым кодом. Поэтому о каких-то особенностях в этом плане говорить не приходится.

Comment: Там дальше указатель на эту переменную преобразуется к `char*`. Я думаю это такой хитрый способ передать в `setsockopt` 4 байта единиц.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb сигнатура у функции такая, что она `char*` хочет. И эффективный тип может быть разный, в зависимости от предыдущих параметров.